# WCF Service with Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I create WCF service library and i test that working fine on WCF Test client(default).
when i host the WCF service in winodws service that time i got the error. I am using windows XP, .Net 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008. and also to set the URL to urlacl concept using HTTPCFG.exe, that time also i got same error that given below.

Error opening host : HTTP could not register URL "http://+:8731/WCFServerDLL/Service1/." Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353" for details).

windows XP sp3.

Here i run the "httpcfg.exe set urlacl /u http://localhost:8731/WCFServerDLL/Service1/ /a "D:...""

i get the result

HttpSetServiceConfiguration completed with 0.

Set the URL also in xp using httpcfg.but i got same error.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add a WCF namespace exception. Use this command

netsh.exe http add urlacl url=http://+:8731/ user={computername}\{username}

Edit:

Im sorry, netsh is for Vista and 7, I just noticed you were on XP. Im not as familiar with XP but I belive the following will work. Make sure to replace myhost.

httpcfg.exe set urlacl /u http://myhost:8731/ /a